# Python Scrapy OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to renaming images and save to targeted folder but it's showing me an error. How can I solve this.

```
import os


class BdstallSpiderPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        os.chdir(r"C:\Users\JohnD\Downloads\Foobar")

        if item['images'][0]['path']:
            new_image_name = item['title'][0] + '.jpg'
            new_image_path = 'full/' + new_image_name

            os.rename(item['images'][0]['path'], new_image_path)
```

Comment: How is this related to scrapy??

Comment: what's the value of `item`. Also consider using `os.path` functions when working with paths, you're clearly using front and back slashes inconsistently

Comment: What does the path in `item['images'][0]['path']` look like? Are the 'raw' strings like your `r"C:\Users\ ...."` ? If not, and they use backwards slashes, this **may** be the problem. Try changing to forward slashes (`/`), or escape all backwards slashes ( ` \\ ` ). And I agree with @Chase : stick to one convention and use `os.path`. It will save you a lot of trouble :)

Comment: thanks for the reply Chase and Magnus and I applied but I'm getting same results :(

Comment: Could you please add your error as well?